# Spawning after travelling

Tags: death-angel, space-hulk

After "travelling" to a new location in Space Hulk Death Angel and setting up the cards, what is the rule for what happens next? Does the "Choose Action Card"  phase occur (so no spawning), the Event phase (and so spawning new Genestealers) or continue from the previous phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should continue from the previous phase.

Travelling always occurs at the end of any phase in which either blip pile is empty, thus you finish resolving the current phase, then resolve travelling.

After this you would continue from where you were up to in the normal order of the game.

I do not have a specific rules reference for this, except that nowhere in the rules does it tell you otherwise. It never states that after travelling you proceed to a specific phase, or skip any phases, it merely says that travelling always happens after the current phase has finished.

[This question on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/572947/travel-question) also supports this order of action.